# How to hide command from htop ubuntu 16.4?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[image]

I have problem in htop in Ubuntu 16.4 server

I have Ubuntu 16.4 Server and I want to hide command from `(htop)` There is an example of pictures

Answer (score -1):

have you tried htop --help ?

-p --pid=PID,[,PID,PID...]  Show only the given PIDs

Now all you need is pgrep to get PIDs.

And as result:

```
htop -p "$(pgrep -vfd, 'snapd|firefox|otherstuff')"
```

Comment: The list of pids isn't going to remain static. Soon there will be a discrepancy between the argument and the processes which are actually running.